# In VS2010 is there a correct placement for private headers and libs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Where should I place `.h` and `.lib` files so that I can just write `#include <mylib.h>` (or `"mylib.h"`) and the compiler and linker will find them for *all* my c++ projects?

Comment: You have to configure that yourself; read the section titled "VC++ Directories change" in [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/02/visual-studio-2010-c-project-upgrade-guide.aspx) for instructions.

Comment: Property sheets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one single place on the computer where you can put .h / .lib files and expect them to be included in all C++ projects.  The directories which are searched for .h / .lib files is a completely configurable item.  Hence there is no one true include directory.

A potential option is changing the global MSBuild files for the machine.  C++ projects inherit a portion of their settings from this file and it could be used to force down a set of includes to the vast majority of projects.  However it's a bit of a sledge hammer option and won't be 100% effective.  Any individual project can still override these defaults (or simply not use MSBuild).

It is possible though to have a unified .h / .lib directory on your machine and then manually point every C++ project at that directory

- Right click on the C++ project
- Navigate to Configuratin Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line
- Add `/I c:\path\to\unified\include`

Comment: "*Even changing the global MSBuild files is not a sure fire approach.*" It's not sure-fire, but you'd have to go out of your way to make it not work; in the general case, changing the global MSBuild files is exactly the right solution, so not explaining it in more detail seems disingenuous to me.

Comment: @ildjarn you don't have to go too far out of the way. All it takes is a single property in an MSBuild file to ignore the defaults from the global MSBuild and specify your own (even seen people do it by mistake).  I'll try to make it clearer though

Comment: `$(IncludePath)` is in Include Directories by default, and likewise `$(LibraryPath)` is in Library Directories by default -- the user would have to remove them, which granted is not difficult, but the defaults allow for changing the global MSBuild files to work as expected here and I would hope that someone wouldn't deviate from the defaults unless they know what they're doing.

Comment: @ildjarn yes but it's not a guarantee. The OP's question emphasized *all* and hence I want to make sure it's clear there is no way to force includes on *all* projects.  Global MSBuild file editing is a way to get *most* but can't guarantee *all*.  It's important the OP understand the limitations of the approaches they are offered

Comment: Fair point, and fully agreed. :-] My only point was that given it works most of the time, some detail as to _how_ to do it could/should be given, as it's certainly less obvious than with previous versions of VC++.

Comment: I am not looking to *enforce* this. I am merely looking for a convenient way to use some of my personal utility functions in my projects without having to manually pull them in to every project.

Comment: @baruch : Then modifying the global or per-user MSBuild files is the way to go.